# jQuery Parallax Jumpy in Safari (background-position is already fixed)

Tags: jquery, safari, parallax

I am trying to implement a parallax scroll effect using this plugin: http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/

Here is my URL. You will see that my setup is very similar, including CSS and parallax initialization. http://pollenbrands.com/rjo/juice/

The background is already fixed, just as in the demo, which is the solution I've seen posted for this issue. The demo works fine in Safari, but mine doesn't. I'm not sure what I'm doing differently at this point.

Thanks!

Comment: Also, when I remove the property background-attachment: fixed, the jumping actually stops. But then the position of the background is off.

Comment: Hi. I know it's 18 months old but did you find a solid solution?